# DirectX 11 Pixel Shader What Is SV_POSITION?

Tags: directx-11, hlsl, vertex-shader, pixel-shader

I am learning HLSL for DirectX 11, and I was wondering what exactly is the SV_POSITION that is the output for a Vertex Shader, and the input for a Pixel Shader.

1: Is this x,y,z of every pixel on your screen, or of the object?

2: Why is it 4 32bit floats?

3: Do you need this System Variable for the vertex output?

Thank you!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The vertex shader stage only has one required output: the position of the vertex. This value is then used by the fixed-function rasterizer to compute which pixels are being drawn and invoke the pixel shader for each one. That's what the system value semantic `SV_Position` indicates on the output of a vertex shader. A pixel shader doesn't actually need to take the pixel position as input, but it can if that is useful. The input layout must also have a position for the vertex shader which uses the `SV_Position` semantic as well.

A typically set up is:

- Tnput layout describes the positions of the vertices in world space indicated as `SV_Position`. The input layout describes the format of the data.

For example:

```
D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC layout[] =
{
    { "SV_Position", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 0, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
};
```

- Vertex shader input receives that information from the input assembler as decoded by the input layout from the vertex buffer, optionally using an index buffer as well. Whatever format the position is in, typically it's converted to `float` for use by the shader.
- The vertex shader has to produce the output vertex position, again indicated by `SV_Position`. This is the `(x, y)` position of the pixel in normalized coordinates in the range `(-1, -1)` to `(1, 1)`. The `z` is the depth position (used for the depth buffer) in the normalized range `0` to `1`.

For example:

```
float4 VS( float4 Pos : SV_Position ) : SV_Position
{
    return Pos;
}
```

- The pixel shader can optionally take the position, but it doesn't have to. The `(x,y)` are in pixel coordinates. The vertex output ('clip space') is converted to pixels by using the viewport state that was provided in `D3D11_VIEWPORT`.
- The pixel shader must produce a `float4` result marked as `SV_Target`.

For example:

```
// We can omit the position
float4 PS() : SV_Target
{
    return float4( 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f );
}

// Or you can take it as input if that's helpful
float4 PS( float4 Pos : SV_Position ) : SV_Target
{
    return float4( 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f );
}
```

Technically the vertex shader doesn't have to take a position as input. With Shader Model 4.0 or better hardware, you can use the `SV_VertexId` to self-generate the corners of a quad in a vertex shader with code like the following which doesn't make use of any input layout, vertex buffer, or index buffer at all. It still has to produce an output position for the pixel shader of course.

```
VSInputTx VSQuad(uint vI : SV_VertexId)
{
    VSInputTx vout;

    float2 texcoord = float2(vI & 1, vI >> 1);
    vout.TexCoord = texcoord;

    vout.Position = float4((texcoord.x - 0.5f) * 2, -(texcoord.y - 0.5f) * 2, 0, 1);
    return vout;
}
```

> Note that you can use the older Direct3D 9 `POSITION` semantic in pretty much any place that you can use the new `SV_Position` (or `SV_POSITION`) semantic. The only requirement is that you have to be consistent between the input layout and the vertex shader input. Otherwise it will fail to bind.

As you are new to DirectX, I recommend you take a look at the [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started) and in particular the [built-in shader source](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/tree/master/Src/Shaders).

Comment: Thank you!  However, I am still confused ... is the float4 SV_Position input to a Pixel Shader the pixel position of the geometry, or of the screen!  Or is it just the Vertex Output SV_Position (they are the same)?  Because the Pixel Shader is outputting a color, what is this color, the color of the screen in 2D?

Comment: It depends on what you are drawing. If you are drawing a triangle, the vertex shader is run once for each of the three corners, while the pixel shader is run for every pixel the triangle ends up touching. The output of the vertex shader is sent to the [rasterizer hardware](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc627092.aspx) which is responsible for computing the pixel positions from all the state. It then invokes the pixel shader for each pixel it generates.

Comment: AH Thanks!  The SV_Position for the pixel shader (for triangle), is this 3d space still?  What is the X,Y,Z,W values?  Sorry... so many unanswered questions!  Edit:  I am assuming it is just screen position?  Just want to make sure I understand this correctly, as the books ive read ... were not really clear.  Example:  The one book states:  The Rasterizer generates a fragment(what is a fragment?) and the pixel shader works on this fragment.  It doesnt explain what a fragment is ... just that the pixel shader must output color.

Comment: Ill accept your answer, but I guess I need to make another question about this Fragment, and what it means and how it works.

Answer (score 1):

From MSDN link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3dhlsl/dx-graphics-hlsl-semantics#direct3d-9-vpos-and-direct3d-10-sv_position

SV_Position refers to screen space coordinates.

This answers the pending question.