# What is the difference between SV_POSITION and POSITION?

Tags: directx-11, hlsl, direct3d11

While looking at the direct3d11 tutorial sample code,
I saw code that I could not understand in the shader code.

```
struct VS_INPUT
{
    float4 Pos : POSITION;
    float4 Color : COLOR;
};

struct PS_INPUT
{
    float4 Pos : SV_POSITION;
    float4 Color : COLOR;
};
```

VS_INPUT use POSITION and PS_INPUT use SV_POSITION.

What is the difference?

why can't I use POSITION PS_INPUT?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46527515/directx-11-pixel-shader-what-is-sv-position   This might help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DirectX 11 Pixel Shader What Is SV\_POSITION?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46527515/directx-11-pixel-shader-what-is-sv-position)